# Fetch data of certain interval?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table ,I want to fetch attribute time for certain row using some query as.

```
select  view,time from new_table where type="someType";
```

Now for each time entry in above query result I want to fetch records from another table which ocurred in last 1 minute before this time.

```
Result of query
 view1,14:06:45
 view2,14:07:45
 view3,14:08:45
 view4,14:09:45



fetchDataTable should give this output for the data view1,14:06:45

some1,Touchl,1151,547,2020/6/25, 14:05:45,
some2,TouchFl,1151,547,2020/6/25,14:06:14,
some3,TouchFl,1151,547,2020/6/25,14:06:20,
some4,TouchFl,1151,547,2020/6/25,14:06:24,
```

I want to fetch the entries in table say `fetchDataTable` which occurred from time `14:05:45 to 14:06:45`.
The table fetchDataTable also has attribute time .I want to do this for each entry of the result of query!!

Comment: add samples data from both table and then add your expected output from them.

Comment: yes sure i will add

Comment: @Strawberry now is it fine?

Comment: No. It's not fine.

Comment: What is missing you tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Formally:

```
SELECT t1.time, t2.*
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.time BETWEEN t1.time - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AND t1.time
WHERE t1.type = 'someType'
```

or

```
SELECT t1.type, t1.time, t2.*
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.time BETWEEN t1.time - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AND t1.time
```

(the task is not clear enough)